# How to add or register .vmtx file from datastore to host inventory?

Tags: python, pyvmomi

I have created the vm templates on nfs datastore. Now via automation, I am adding that datastore to a standalone ESX host and then I want to register the .vmtx file to ESX host. While the datastore is added to the host through the script, I am not able to register the .vmtx file to the host.

I have tried below code -

```
    si = connect()  # connect method connects to the standalone ESX host. It is NOT part of any VCenter
    content = si.RetrieveContent()
    # nfs_datastore = add_nfsdatastore(content, 'esx-ip', 'nfs-ip', 'nfs-path', 'nfs-name')
    # print("nfs datastore added successfully")
    # print(nfs_datastore)
    host = content.rootFolder.childEntity[0]
    host_folder  = host.vmFolder
    print(host_folder)
    hostobj = content.searchIndex.FindByIp(None, "esx-ip",vmSearch=False)
    host_folder.RegisterVM_Task("[nfs-datastore-name]/my-template/ubuntu-temp-1.vmtx", "automation-template-1", asTemplate=True, host=hostobj)
```

I am getting below error -

''' Failed - The operation is not supported on the object. '''

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. I was giving incorrect value for pool and asTemplate parameters.

```
si = connect()  # connect method connects to the standalone ESX host. It is NOT part of any VCenter
    content = si.RetrieveContent()
    # nfs_datastore = add_nfsdatastore(content, 'esx-ip', 'nfs-ip', 'nfs-path', 'nfs-name')
    # print("nfs datastore added successfully")
    # print(nfs_datastore)
    host = content.rootFolder.childEntity[0]
    host_folder  = host.vmFolder
    print(host_folder)
    hostobj = content.searchIndex.FindByIp(None, "esx-ip",vmSearch=False)
    resource_pool = hostobj.vm[0].resourcePool
    host_folder.RegisterVM_Task(path="[nfs-datastore-name]/my-template/ubuntu-temp-1.vmtx", name="automation-template-1", asTemplate=False, pool=resource_pool, host=hostobj)
```